# Import text files to excel and create master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am a grad student and I collect a lot of data that is stored in txt files.  I want to import the text files as a fixed width, columns a, b and c all are 12, then save those files as excel files and then move them into a master workbook. I found the following code that worked for making the master workbook but it does not import them in numerical order.

I am using Microsoft 2010.

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyPath = "C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Scan Rate Study 1-14-16"
Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until strFilename = ""
Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)
Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)
wbSrc.Close False
strFilename = Dir()
Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the naming convention of your .xls files in the directory? Are they in numeric order?

Comment: I keep them the same as the text file.  It is usually KAVCVXXX the X being some number and yes they are always in order

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [FSO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278516.aspx) object to traverse the `MyPath` directory and copy over the `.xls` files. Currently, your set up was importing all Excel like files located in directory:

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim wbDst As Workbook, wbSrc As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object, olFolder As Object, olFile As Object

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Scan Rate Study 1-14-16"

    Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set olFolder = fso.GetFolder(MyPath)

    For Each olFile In olFolder.Files
        If Right(olFile.Name, 4) = ".xls" Then

            Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(olFile.Name)
            Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
            wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)
            wbSrc.Close False

        End If
    Next olFile

    wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set olFile = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```